# How to get mapped path in jersey

Tags: jersey-1.0

Please refer following code. /hello/from/JohnDoe will hit the method sayPlainTextHello. When "/hello/from/JohnDoe" is accessed, I want to store the mapped path which is /hello/from/{name} in a log. Please note that I can't modify below code but can add filter, etc. to the app. How to get the mapped path "/hello/from/{name}" ?

```
    @Path("hello")
    public class GenericResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Path("/from/{name}")
        public String sayPlainTextHello(@PathParam("name") String fromName) {
            return "Hello Jersey - " + fromName;
        }
    }
```